# Defining an array with an equilibrium such that all points either side sum to be the same

Tags: number-theory

I've decided to learn Python and wanted to chuck myself right into the deep end. One practice program I have found is to define a zero indexed array, consisting of $n$ integers.

An "equilibrium index" of this array is an integer $P: 0 \leq P < n$, and the sum of the elements of the lower indices is equal to the sum of the elements of the higher indices.

In other words:

$A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P−1] = A[P+1] + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1].$

For example, if we have the following array $A$ consisting of $n=8$ elements:

$A[0] = -1, A[1] = 3, A[2] = -4, A[3] = 5, A[4] = 1, A[5] = -6, A[6] = 2, A[7]= 1$

Here, we have three equilibrium points at $P = 1,3,7$.

Using $P = 1$, we see that this gives:

LHS: $-1 = -1$

RHS: $-4 + 5 + 1 - 6 + 2 + 1 = -1 =$ LHS

Now, I think I need to code this function for any integer $n$, but I can't even define an array like this mathematically, let alone learn how to code it.

Can someone give me any pointers in how I would define this array for all possible integers $n$.

Comment: m.se is not a coding site. I'd recommend posting your question to a coding site.

Comment: I don't need help in coding it. I'm sure I can figure that bit out. The bit I'm stuck on is exactly what it is that I need to code, and that's the mathematical part.

Comment: Then I guess I don't uderstand how "define an array" isn't a coding question. Maybe you could reephrase it.

Comment: Hmmm. I was under the impression that an array was a mathematical term, sort of like a matrix? So I have to define this "set" of numbers? I don't think I've understood this exercise at all...

Comment: OK, "array" is a mathematical term. Now, you write, "One practice program I have found is to define a zero indexed array...." The word "program" tells me that, so far, we're talking about a coding problem, not a math problem. Then you write, "I can't even define an array like this mathematically...." I don't know what that means. Are you asking for the dictionary definition of the word, "array"? You've got a list of numbers, $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ (I hope you don't mind if I go 1 to $n$ instead of 0 to $n-1$). Let $S$ be their sum. Then you want all $r$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_r=S/2$. (ctd.)

Comment: (ctd.) So what exactly is it that you want to define?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.